# Physical security for Servers

Tags: security, physical-security

I work in a non-profit and we need to upgrade the physical security around our new servers and DC. We can't secure the entire room, and we can't afford to purchase a proper server rack. The workaround is that the equipment will be in a nook that has walls on three sides, and we will use some sort of locking security door. However, I am struggling to locate anything that would suffice as a locking security door. I am here to ask for resources and knowledge on the topic. If anyone here has knowledge of affordable, non-standard, physical security options.

Comment: Keep in mind the size of your new "enclosure" and make sure that there is air flow so your servers don't overheat.

Comment: Whatever you do, please just be mindful of the running state of your equipment. I know that non-profits do not have much to spend, but losing your servers because you couldn't afford a decent secure door, or put them in a nook with no ventilation and they melted, is very expensive as well!

Comment: Thank you. The space is air conditioned, and I am making sure to allow ventilation. Ideally, I would like to locate/create a security door that facilitates airflow for that same reason. Someone mentioned constructing a door by hand with wire mesh, but I don't know how practical that is.

Comment: @Warn What is a DC?

Comment: Domain controller.

Comment: Don't just think in terms of security door - think in terms of auditing/traceability. A camera that takes pictures of anyone opening the door and sends them to an external drive will let you know who's been at the server at a given time, which a locked door opened using a regular key won't.

Comment: @JennyD [X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... (so glad there's a Wikipedia entry for this now!)

Answer (score 5):

A server rack should not be cost-prohibitive.

Open-frame racks are cheap, and absolutely available locally refurbished or used.

Regular server enclosures are also available used. That's a easy way to accomplish what you need within your financial constraints.

My advice is to focus on obtaining the budget for proper purpose-built equipment and not try desperate workarounds.

Comment: My two servers are 9" x 27" x18" and my DC is 28" x 19" Unless I'm making a mistake, which is possible, the cost for a rack unit big enough to fit all of that is beyond my current budget, even when the units are refurbished. Any open-frame racks would need a secure door as well. I do not have the ability to expand my budget.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a server that you can close the front with a key and leave it in a closet somewhere or under your desk.

You don't state if you fear someone that pick the entire server out, or just to protect the disk to stay there.

Most non-profit I seen just put the server in a closet, in a wardroom room or under the front secretary desk.

It exist some cheap 12U/24U rack too, it's not only full 48U rack too. It could cost less a small no-name rack than to try to buy a door for your nook setup.

Comment: My two servers are 9" x 27" x18" and my DC is 28" x 19" Unless I'm making a mistake, which is possible, the cost for a rack unit big enough to fit all of that is beyond my current budget.

Comment: @Warn On ebay there is cheap rack, 140$ and less, but again we try to offer the best option, for homemade project DIY (diy.stackexchange.com) is maybe a better fit for your question.